# Slow Excel report with MySQL queries inside nested foreach loops [Laravel 5.3]

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.3, maatwebsite-excel

I'm facing a problem with slow times creating XLS/XLSX reports using  [Maatwebsite](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs) plugin for Laravel (around 5 - 30, 30 - 60 mins depending on the conditions of the report) which is a lot of time!!.

Searching through the web I encountered that Maatwebsite uses PHPExcel, which is slow and memory consuming if there's a lot or registers in the generation of the XLS/XLSX file.

Checking times, I have encountered that my queries grow almost exponentially because of nested foreach loops, the basic generation of the report is this:

```
$clients = Client::all(); // can change depending on conditions, worse case with all clients
Excel::create('Client Statement', function($excel) use ($clients) {
     $excel->sheet('Sheet 1', function($sheet) {
          $row = 1; // row number
          foreach($clients as $client) {
               $sheet->row($row++, [$client->data1,...,$client->dataN]);

               $charges = Charge::get_ByClient($client->id);

               foreach($charges as $charge) {
                    $sheet->row($row++, [$charge->data1,...,$charge->dataN]);

                    $payments = Payment::get_ByCharge($charge->id);

                    foreach($payments as $payment) {
                         $sheet->row($row++, [$payment->data1,...,$payment->dataN]);
                    }
               }
          }
     });
});
```

The basic explination is:

1. Get all clients
2. For every client, get all the charges
3. For every charge, get all the payments

The problem is, I have around 1500 clients, every client can have betwee 10 - 100 charges, and every charge can have between 1 - 5 payments which results in slow performance. To that, sum the time the library takes to generate the XLS/XLSX file.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a CSV instead of an XLS?

Comment: unfortunately that is not an option in this case....

Comment: Setting up relations between clients, charges and payments and retrieving all those relations when you get clients would be a good way to reduce the high number of SQL queries that you're executing

Comment: @MarkBaker do you mean using Eloquent's relationships? hasMay, belongsTo, etc??

Comment: @JoseAntonioDominguez - precisely

Comment: @MarkBaker just tried that and didn't work, it's a lot slower actually, just getting all the charges for a range of 5 clients gets 24 seconds using Eloquent's relationships, and using raw queries (as i do now) gets 1.4 seconds

Comment: If the queries take that long, then perhaps you also need to look at the indexes on your tables... I know that both Eloquent and PHPExcel can be inefficient, but that seems excessive when 10000 of individual database queries is an order of magnitude faster than a very few queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify this, I indeed used Eloquent's relationships as @Mark Baker suggested to speed up things, my problem was the typical N + 1 Problem. To resolve this issue I used [Laravel's Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships)

Answer (score 1):

**If I understood you correctly.
You can use the following example.
Works great.
Taken from** 
[http://www.websleson.info/2016/02/ex](http://www.webslesson.info/2016/02/export-mysql-data-to-excel-in-php-php-tutorial.html)

CREATE MYSQL TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_customer` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CustomerName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `City` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `PostalCode` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `Country` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;


INSERT INTO `tbl_customer` (`id`, `CustomerName`, `Address`, `City`, `PostalCode`, `Country`) VALUES
(1, 'Maria Anders', 'Obere Str. 57', 'Berlin', 12209, 'Germany'),
(2, 'Ana Trujillo', 'Avda. de la Construction 2222', 'Mexico D.F.', 5021, 'Mexico');
```

INDEX.PHP

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_customer";  
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
?>
<html>  
 <head>  
  <title>Export MySQL data to Excel in PHP</title>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
 </head>  
 <body>  
  <div class="container">  
   <br />  
   <br />  
   <br />  
   <div class="table-responsive">  
    <h2 align="center">Export MySQL data to Excel in PHP</h2><br /> 
    <table class="table table-bordered">
     <tr>  
                         <th>Name</th>  
                         <th>Address</th>  
                         <th>City</th>  
       <th>Postal Code</th>
       <th>Country</th>
                    </tr>
     <?php
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
     {  
        echo '  
       <tr>  
         <td>'.$row["CustomerName"].'</td>  
         <td>'.$row["Address"].'</td>  
         <td>'.$row["City"].'</td>  
         <td>'.$row["PostalCode"].'</td>  
         <td>'.$row["Country"].'</td>
       </tr>  
        ';  
     }
     ?>
    </table>
    <br />
    <form method="post" action="export.php">
     <input type="submit" name="export" class="btn btn-success" value="Export" />
    </form>
   </div>  
  </div>  
 </body>  
</html>
```

EXSPORT.PHP

```
<?php  
//export.php  
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");
$output = '';
if(isset($_POST["export"]))
{
 $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_customer";
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
 {
  $output .= '
   <table class="table" bordered="1">  
                    <tr>  
                         <th>Name</th>  
                         <th>Address</th>  
                         <th>City</th>  
       <th>Postal Code</th>
       <th>Country</th>
                    </tr>
  ';
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
   $output .= '
    <tr>  
                         <td>'.$row["CustomerName"].'</td>  
                         <td>'.$row["Address"].'</td>  
                         <td>'.$row["City"].'</td>  
       <td>'.$row["PostalCode"].'</td>  
       <td>'.$row["Country"].'</td>
                    </tr>
   ';
  }
  $output .= '</table>';
  header('Content-Type: application/xls');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=download.xls');
  echo $output;
 }
}
?>
```